# 'MySQL' object has no attribute connection while using mysql.connection.cursor()

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Actual code is

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

mysql=MySQL(app)
mysql.connection.cursor()
```

I just changed the library flask_mysqldb to flaskext.mysql because I am getting some error while installing flask_mysqldb library.

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql=MySQL(app)
mysql.connection.cursor()
```

What is wrong with this code? and also suggest best way of connecting to MySQL database using Flask?

Thanks

Comment: You should read [the docs for flask-mysql](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered the same error while doing Flask. But it fixed it after doing the following commands:

```
pip install flask-mysqldb  
pip install flask
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL    

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'DbToConnect'
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'

#Initialize the app for use with this MySQL class
mysql.init_app(app)

cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

[More information](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_mysqldb.MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, tried everything and couldn't find any answers that solved it...

After rewriting the entire script it somehow worked, so I thought what's wrong with my original script?

Apparently there were some indentation errors (invisible) in my script. It didn't give me the indentation errors, but figured it out by removing code.

If there are some spaces where tabs should be it doesn't recognise the `.connection` attribute somehow. Fixed the original script by backspacing everywhere! :))

Hope this helps for some people in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I have looked everywhere and well researched into different solutions. I have come closer to the solution by reducing the number of errors. Here is my piece of code that's giving me a headache

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'BucketList'

mysql.init_app(app)
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

I have been running the app.py file and keep getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connection'.

I am using MySQL 5.7 and attempting to create my first web app using a tutorial that's dated back in time. The above piece of code is after editing it closer to relevant standards.

Comment: That's definitely not an answer to the question.